# Make shape draggable after user draws it

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm pretty new to d3 and just getting the hang of it. I have code that lets a user draw a circle on mousedown. Here's the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/amwill/HhLVt/

```
function getRadius(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
return Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + (Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2))));
}
var circle, isDown = false, m1, m2;
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.on("mousedown", mousedown);
function mousedown() {
if (!isDown) {
    m1 = d3.mouse(this);
    circle = vis.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", m1[0])
        .attr("cy", m1[1])
        .attr("r", 0);
}
isDown = !isDown;
vis.on("mousemove", mousemove);
}
function mousemove() {
m2 = d3.mouse(this);
if (isDown) {
    m2 = d3.mouse(this);
    circle.attr("r", getRadius(m1[0], m1[1], m2[0],m2[1]));
}
}
```

But I want to have that shape draggable after the user draws it. I know d3 has drag functionality but I'm not quite sure how to implement it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I believe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/iweczek/KDnVR/1/) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: That was a little complicated for this particular problem but I think it will be helpful in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Here's a simple example of draggable circles http://jsfiddle.net/uAwkA/ to reference

Comment: I ended up doing it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/amwill/HhLVt/3/

Comment: Would you mind adding this as an answer for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it, I used d3.behavior.drag(). [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amwill/HhLVt/3)

```
function getRadius(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + (Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2))));
}

var circle, isDown = false, cDown = false, isDragging = false, m1, m2,
    width = 800, height = 600, cx = 0, cy = 0, radius = 0;

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
 .on("drag", dragmove);

function dragmove() {    
    var initialX = this.getAttribute("cx"), initialY = this.getAttribute("cy");
    d3.select(this) 
       .attr("cx", +initialX + d3.event.dx)
       .attr("cy", +initialY + d3.event.dy);
}

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",width).attr("height",height)
    .on("mousedown", mousedown1);

function mousedown1() { 
    if (!isDown && !isDragging) {
        m1 = d3.mouse(this);
        circle = vis.append("circle")
           .attr("cx", m1[0])
           .attr("cy", m1[1])
           .attr("r", 0)
           .call(drag);
} else {
    cDown = !cDown;
    circle.on("mousedown", mousedown2);
    function mousedown2() {
        isDragging = true;
    } 
    circle.on("mouseup", mouseup);
    function mouseup(e) {
        isDragging = isDown = false;
        cDown = !cDown;            
    }
}   
isDown = !isDown;    
}

vis.on("mousemove", mousemove);
function mousemove() {
    m2 = d3.mouse(this);
    if (isDown && !isDragging) {
        m2 = d3.mouse(this);
        circle.attr("r", getRadius(m1[0], m1[1], m2[0],m2[1]));
    }
}
```